# running a .net web service on iis6 deployed on windows 2003 server sp2

Tags: service, iis-6, deployment

To whom it may respond to,
We have deployed a web service to Windows 2003 Server SP2 , .net framework 3.5 .
"The service is not running , we are getting the error : 
  The website declined to show this webpage 
 HTTP 403
   Most likely causes:
•This website requires you to log in.

What you can try: 
     Go back to the previous page.

```
 More information
```

This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.

For more information about HTTP errors, see Help."

We have played around with the permissions but the situation didn't change a bit.

We would be very glad ideas on it,

Thank you for your concern,

Best Regards,

Kayhan YUKSEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have aspnet_isapi.dll as your wildcard handler in the Virtual Directory setup.  Properties --> Virtual Directory --> Configuration --> Insert... --> aspnet_isapi.dll, make sure you uncheck Verify that file exists.

Comment: Noe after deployment and invoking a method as an example, entering username for a login method, we get error code 500 internal server error at the webpage as a result.

Comment: internal test IIs in vs runs the ws and we get the user data in xml format but when deployed to iis we get the internal server error code 500

Comment: tim, your case had appeared in once and repeating steps made it go.